# Example of relative reference not working as expected

Tags: libreoffice-calc

See image for example of relative refrence that is not working as expected (to me).

[image: Relative refrence example]

As seen in picture, example 1 does not give me the expected value. The matching string "E4" is not absolute "$" so i would think that it would turn into E5 from E4 1 row down.

Is there an easy work around for this problem?
Edit, dynamic solution. Static as displayed in example is not an option.

I assume the problem is that "=F4" means an exact copy of that cell, therefore E4(ID1) instead of E5(ID2)

Kind Regards,
/Robin

Comment: You're misunderstanding what relative references are. `=F4` means that cell F5 returns the same value as what's in F4. Drag the formula down or copy paste if you actually want to look up `ID2`.

Comment: Yes, that is what i assumed. Is there any easy solution for it to work that way though?
Guess you could use indirect in some way to construct the refrence to that cell but ive heard that comes with performance issues. Dont want to go there if there is an easy solution.

Comment: Copy paste the formula or drag down.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, copy paste/drag down is not dynamic therefore not a solution in this case.

Comment: [Not so sure about that](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/ro/text/scalc/guide/relativ_absolut_ref.html).

Comment: from link 

"Relative here means that the reference to this area will be adjusted automatically when you copy the formulas."

This is what i would expect from the above example as E4 is not set as absolute. I do understand that refrence being absolute or relative for this case is not even considered.